# Get Dropdown selected text via Gridview javascript onclick

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with a few labels and two DropDownList controls. At the end of each row, I have a "Print" button (normal form button, not asp button).  The onclick event produces javascript and passes in values from the grid.

How do I get the Dropdownlist values?

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button" 
            style="font-size: 18px" 
            onclick="javascript:jsWebClientPrint.print('useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked') + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val() + '&lblNDC=<%# Eval("CODE1") %>    ' + '&unit=<%# Eval("ddUnit.Text") %>    ');" 
            value="Print" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

It doesn't like trying to Eval ddUnit.Text, but that's the value I'm trying to pass as a URL variable.

Comment: you are using the library jquery right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hardly the most elegant solution, but you could continue along the jquery path to get the `DropDownList` value:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button" style="font-size:18px" onclick="javascript:jsWebClientPrint.print('useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked') + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val() + '&lblNDC=<%# Eval("CODE1") %>' + '&unit=' + $('#<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("ddUnit").ClientID %>').text());" value="Print" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: This almost worked. It doesn't take the selected value, it passes in all possible values for the dropdown.  I tried .text and .value, but neither worked.

Comment: $('#<%= ddUnit.ClientID %> option:selected').val();  You put me on the right track. Many thanks.

Comment: Gah! Of course `option:selected`...my mistake. Glad it got you going though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlUnit" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="text1" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="text2" Value="2" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button"
            style="font-size: 18px"
            onclick='<%# "MyPrintWrapper(this, \""+ Eval("CODE1") + "\")" %>'
            value="Print" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

JavaScript

```
function MyPrintWrapper(elm, code) {
    var paramString = 'useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked')
        + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val()
        + '&lblNDC=' + code
        //take the clicked button, find its row, 
        //then find the dropdownlist using its class name
        + '&unit=' + $(elm).closest("tr").find(".ddlUnit").val();
    //console.log(paramString);
    jsWebClientPrint.print(paramString);
}
```

Here we created a class name for the dropdownlist and a wrapper js function so that markup looks cleaner.